# PeopleSoft AE with GetNextNumberWithGapsCommit function erroring out initially, but goes to success later on

Tags: peoplesoft

Production environment-> 2 app server domains, 2 web server domains, 3 process schedulers [AIX, 1 NT], NON RAC Oracle DB

PT 8.55.15, HCM 9.2 DB 12.2.0.1

We are running a custom AE program in our production environment. This AE that calls delivered EOEN application packages. No customization's have been made in this package. Custom component interface is also involved. This AE has been running in our environment since 5 years ago. No change has been done to the code in near past.

This AE has been behaving very weirdly since some 2-3 weeks ago. It errors out for the first time but goes to success when re-run in second/third run. We are not changing any parameters nor bouncing any services in second/third run. This application package [EOEN_MVC.EOEN_MODEL] makes calls to PeopleCode function - GetNextNumberWithGapsCommit.

We had set trace on this AE and found that the program goes to error every time the "GetNextNumberWithGapsCommit" function is called. These are the lines from the trace:

> 3905919 23:51:18.263     0.005472 Cur#8.15073404.HCMPRO RC=0
>   Dur=0.000094 COM Stmt=SELECT DESCR,DESCRLONG FROM PS_EOEN_REGE_LNG
>   WHERE EOEN_EVENT_NAME=:1 AND LANGUAGE_CD = :2
>
> 3905920 23:51:18.264     0.000974 Cur#8.15073404.HCMPRO RC=0
>   Dur=0.000001 Bind-1 type=2 length=16 value=CreateTriggerESP
>
> 3905921 23:51:18.265     0.000966 Cur#8.15073404.HCMPRO RC=0
>   Dur=0.000000 Bind-2 type=2 length=3 value=ESP
>
> 3905922 23:51:18.270     0.004369              258:       If
>   All(&RS_RegEvnt(1).EOEN_REG_EVNT.EOEN_EVENT_NAME.Value) Then
>
> 3905923 23:51:18.271     0.001026                       Fetch Field:
>   EOEN_REG_EVNT.EOEN_EVENT_NAME Value=CreateTriggerESP
>
> 3905924 23:51:18.272     0.001004              259:
>   &NextEventID = GetNextNumberWithGapsCommit(EOEN_CONFIG.EOEN_LAST_ID,
>   2147483647, 1);
>
> 3905925 23:51:18.273     0.001065 Cur#7.15073404.HCMPRO RC=0
>   Dur=0.000031 COM Stmt=UPDATE PS_EOEN_CONFIG SET EOEN_LAST_ID =
>   EOEN_LAST_ID + 1
>
> 3905926 23:51:18.274     0.001453 Cur#2.15073404.HCMPRO RC=0
>   Dur=0.000042 COM Stmt=SELECT
>   TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF') FROM PSCLOCK
>
> 3905927 23:51:18.278     0.003895             Caught Exception: Error
>   grave de SQL. (2,125) EOEN_MVC.EOEN_MODEL.EOENInterface.OnExecute 
>   Name:RaiseEvent  PCPC:14959 Statement:259
>
> Called from:FUNCLIB_HR_ESP.TRGR_FUNCTIONS_ESP.FieldFormula 
>   Name:Create_Triggers_ESP  Statement:60
>
> Called from:JOB.REPORTS_TO.SavePostChange  Statement:3

Error message in the process monitor is same as above:-

> Error -> Error grave de SQL. (2,125)
>   EOEN_MVC.EOEN_MODEL.EOENInterface.OnExecute Name:RaiseEvent PCPC:14959
>   Statement:259 Called
>   from:FUNCLIB_HR_ESP.TRGR_FUNCTIONS_ESP.FieldFormula
>   Name:Create_Triggers_ESP Statement:60 Called
>   from:JOB.REPORTS_TO.SavePostChange Statement:3

I have tried keeping the DBFlags parameter as "8" and "0" in both application server and process schedulers.

I also checked the EOEN_MSG_CHNL queue, its associated service operation EOEN_MSG, handlers, routings etc. Everything is active and running. No failed IB messages. Domain status active.

Nothing works. And the error remains.

Any suggestions may be of great help.

Comment: Whats the value on the record `EOEN_CONFIG` field `EOEN_LAST_ID`?

Comment: Hi Walcus,   EOEN_LAST_ID is not blank. Currently, it has a value of 7114635

Comment: Which tools and version of HR are u?